# Does hostmaster email needs to be in same domain as defined in zone file?

Tags: ubuntu, bind, dns-zone

I am going through Bind9 to configure DNS server for my domains, but during this process I am confused about points one of them is, when we put email address in zone file do I need to put hostmaster email address with same domain name that I am using in zone configuration file?

For example I have created zone for "example.com". Do I then have to put xxx.example.com in forward zone file or can I put main email in all configurations?

```
$TTL    86400   
@   IN  SOA     ns1.example.com. myemail.gmail.com (
20081112001 ; Serial
28800   : Refresh (s)
3600    ; Retry (s)
604800  ; Expiration (s)
38400   ; Negative Cache TTL (s)
)
;
@   IN  NS  ns1
@   IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it does not need to be in the same domain.**

However, it is very common to use `hostmaster.example.com`, either matching the domain part of the name server or the preferred domain of the organization/company (e.g. `example.net`, `example.com` & `icann.org` all use the same SOA rname).

The recommendation in [RFC 2142 Section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2142#section-7) conflicts with using something like a gmail address:

> For simplicity and regularity, it is strongly recommended that the
> well known mailbox name HOSTMASTER always be used `<HOSTMASTER@domain>`.

The most important question however, remains whether *even when your DNS is broken* your hosting providers have reliable means of contacting you.

Caveat: Just because you publish your preferred methods of contact in whois, SOA, [Impressum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressum), [security.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security.txt) etc. does not mean they will be used that way.
I have received inquiries to `hostmaster@domain.example` without ever publishing such address in the SOA record of `domain.example`, which is a good argument in favor of unconditionally setting up `hostmaster` as an alias.